# cocoa app works under 10.7 but it doesn't under 10.6

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, osx-snow-leopard, backwards-compatibility

i try to deploy the app for both 10.6 and 10.7.
i set deployment target to 10.6 and base SDK to 10.6 on XCode.
It is a status bar application, which means it doesn't have a main window.
One `nsmenuitem` triggers the method `-(void)openCreateNewWindow` which opens a `nswindow`.
On 10.7 it works fine but on 10.6 even if the app starts working normally, the `nsmenuitem` pressed doesn't open the window.
What is going wrong?
The method that opens the window looks like this:

```
-(void)openCreateNewWindow{
    //supportWindow is a subclass of NSWindowController
    supportWindow *sw = [[supportWindow alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"createNewPanel"];
    addPanel = [sw window];  //addPanel is a public var of NSWindow type
    [addPanel center];
    [addPanel setTitle:@"foo"];
    [sw showWindow:self];

}
```

Comment: You should be setting your SDK to the latest SDK. As you already have the deployment target to 10.6 this should be fine. You should generally set your SDK to the latest SDK and set the deployment target to the oldest OS you plan on running on.

Comment: this is what i tried in the first place but i still had the same problem.